# How to avoid UnboundLocalError?

Tags: python-3.x, boolean

While making one of my programs I've been stuck with this error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'bool' referenced before assignment

In order to show the problem, I've written a little code that has the same error as in my current project.

```
def bool():
    bool = True
def func():
    while bool:
        print("Everything's ok!")
        bool = False
bool()
func()
```

How can make "Everything's ok!" be printed only once without using "bool = False"?

Comment: Why are you naming your variable the same as your function name?Also bool is a python builtin, don't use it as a variable name, seems like you don't need `bool` function at all

Comment: "_How can make "Everything's ok!" be printed only once without using "bool = False"?_" Remove the while-loop?

Comment: You're sharing a single variable across two functions. Why not do `def func(): bool_ = True; while bool: ...`? Or is your project a lot more complicated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def bool():
    global bool
    bool = True
def func():
    while bool:
        print("Everything's ok!")
        break
bool()
func()
```